# How to uninstall Android Studio completely from Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, software-uninstall, android-studio

I want to uninstall Android Studio completely from Ubuntu but i can't figure out how to do it.

I installed it following the [instructions on the Android website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio).

Comment: Is it possible to install it in the first place? I just downloaded the Android Studio archive and simply unzipped it. If I'd want to "uninstall" it I'd just delete the directory where I unzipped it.

Comment: Did you install it from some PPA?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the informations how you installed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you installed it from Android website, then do `rm -r` the directory into which you extracted the `android-studio-ide-141.1890965-linux.zip` file.

Also remove `.AndroidStudioPreview` (or `.AndroidStudio1.3` etc., depending on version) which generally resides in your home directory (`/home/your-username/`).

If you see the `android-studio` folder in your `/home/user-name/android-studio`, remove that too.